# How does one concatenate fields in title field in Panels (Pages)?

Tags: entities, panels

I have learned how to concatenate fields in Views, now I need to do the same thing in the title field in Panels. I have these fields
- first name
- last name

and I would like the title of the Panel to be
first name + last name

I'm using a module which enables me to automatically update the title field and hides it. The automatic generation includes the first and last name plus the date. I don't want this to display on top of the panel for this content type.

TIA

Comment: Are you using a custom page via Panels? Overriding the node_view template?

Comment: Yes, I'm overriding the node_view template in Panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use replacements tokens in your "Content" configuration page, this is how is looks on my local instance:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: If we need to add a prefix for firstname %node:field_firstname like `His name is %node:field_firstname`, its not working for me?